# C#, How to mock Azure Subscriptions - List Locations

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mocking, cloud

I need to implement method with mocks for get physical regions of
[Azure Subscriptions - List Locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list-locations?tabs=HTTP),
not sure how it should look

`public async Task<IEnumerable<Region>> GetPhysicalRegions(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)){}`

Comment: Please provide what is the error what you got and what you tried so that community would help you better!

Comment: Actually I don't have any error, I need to implement the method. I'm not sure what should be the start point for picking it [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list-locations?tabs=HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You make an implementation of a HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory as defined on this page, pick the solution that's most suitable for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Then, if you implement an interface, for example IMyAzureClient, then you can create a stub or mock for where-ever you inject this interface.

```
public sealed class MyAzureClientTests
{
    private Mock<HttpMessageHandler> _httpMessageHandlerMock;

    private MyAzureClient _sut;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _httpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://unit-tests:1337/");
        _sut = new MyAzureclient(
            httpClient,
        );
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task YourTest()
    {
        // arrange
        var inputModel = new Fixture().Create<SomeInputModel>();
        var expectedJson = "{}";
        
        _httpMessageHandlerMock.Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent(expectedJson, Encoding.UTF8)
            }).Verifiable();
        
        // act
        var actual = await _sut.SomeMethodAsync(inputModel);

        // assert
        _httpMessageHandlerMock.Protected().Verify(
            "SendAsync",
            Times.Once(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        );
        Assert.AreEqual(Guid.Parse("efc6f86b-f40c-4dce-baef-3bfae0bcdb08"), actual.MyProperty);
    }
```

If you're running this in a development environment, consider using stubs, and simulate the behavior based on the parameters it receives.